ArcGIS Pro 3.3.x Crashes when opening a layout tab in an APRX
In the past couple of weeks I've run into an issue with ArcGIS Pro 3.3.x crashing when I try to open an APRX that was closed on a layout tab, open a layout.pagx by double clicking, or import a layout into an APRX.
I thought it might have had something to do with hosting all my data in a NAS but now it's happening even on my C Drive with a bare bones sort of layout.pagx.
Is anyone else having this issue?
I opened up a ticket with ESRI but of course they are not able to reproduce the issue on their end. I'll continue to work with them and my IT department.
I'm using Windows 11 x64 and have Desktop Runtime 8.0.5 installed.

It's been a few years since I used ESRI tech support but they did have an option to share one's screen with them so they could watch and have you manipulate your computer.  They also for years would begin by asking a caller to reset their application data profile.  If you haven't I would try that.   I also would do a repair on the installation, which usually didn't help but over many years it helped a few times and it is relatively easy.

Hi John, I tried the two things you suggested but no luck. If you have any other tricks to try let me know!

Turns out I had a couple of third party Add-ins that weren't compatible with ArcGIS Pro 3.0+. After removing the Add-ins, I was able to open layouts again.
